# Postgres: Query with multiple (partially) overlapping data sources

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple data sources (4 at the moment, could theoretically increase in the future) feeding into multiple PostgreSQL tables and would like to create a view comparing the different sources for each entry. Unfortunately not all entries appear in every table

Currently the query I'm using is formatted like this

```
select [relevant_fields] from ((tableA full outer join tableB on 
    tableA.id=tableB.id) full outer join tableC on tableA.id=tableC.id)
    full outer join tableD on tableD.id=tableA.id
```

The issue with this query is that if an entry is in tables B,C, and D but not in tableA then it turns into 3 (mostly null) rows, one for each data source. I realize that there's a way to do this via upserting into a secondary table but was wondering if there was any way to do this directly in a select/view as some of these tables are quite large and will only get larger and I'd rather not run into a memory issue down the road because I have multiple copies of each record stored.

So my question is: is there a way to structure joins to accomplish 1 (as filled in as possible) row per entry in a select/view?

Edit, Sample Data:

```
Table A
id | value
1  | a
2  | b
3  | c

Table B
id | value
1  | A
3  | Z

Table C
id | value
1  | Q
4  | D

Table D
id | value
1  | a
3  | C

Result
id | val_A | val_B | val_C | val_D
1  |  a    |  A    |  Q    |  a  
2  |  b    |  null |  null |  null
3  |  c    |  Z    |  null |  C
4  |  null |  null |  D    |  null
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example query could be simplified:

```
select [relevant_fields]
from
  tableA full join 
  tableB using(id) full join
  tableC using(id) full join
  tableD using(id);
```

And it should work as you want.

In that case if referenced fields have different name you could to rename them using table aliases, like this:

```
select [relevant_fields]
from
  tableA as tableA(i,val_a) full join 
  tableB as tableB(i,val_b) using(i) full join
  tableC as tableC(i,val_c) using(i) full join
  tableD as tableD(i,val_d) using(i);
```

And it also produces desired names of columns `val_*`.

<kbd>[Example](http://rextester.com/BUZFU97646)</kbd>

Read about `USING` clause [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

Comment: Appears to work perfectly, haven't run into USING before, thanks!